# Why Android Studio keeps re-creating previously deleted files when I compile

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 3.4 keeps re-creating files I deleted previously (sometimes weeks ago).

What I tried and didn't help:

- Clean
- Rebuild
- Invalidation caches Restart
- Close and restart AS

The project is regularly saved. So I am not sure why AS is bringing back old files.

Comment: What files are you talking about?

Comment: files in the JAVA folder